# I am not getting the value of a variable inside a function's parameter in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two functions in the model of my website. The functions in the model are:

```
public function get_like($array){
    return $this->db->select('is_liked')
                         ->from('ims_likes')
                         ->where($array)
                         ->get()->row();

  }
```

And, the second one is,

```
public function showpost()
  {
    $user_id = $this->session->userdata('user_id');
    $query = $this->db->select('ims_posts.post_file, ims_admin.name, ims_posts.created_at, ims_posts.post_description, ims_posts.post_id')
                      ->from('ims_posts')
                      ->where('user_id', $user_id)
                      ->join('ims_admin', 'ims_admin.admin_id = ims_posts.user_id')
                      ->get()->result_array();
    return $query;

  }
```

I am using these function in my controller, just as below:

```
function like(){
    $posts = $this->umodel->showpost();
    //echo "<pre>"; print_r($posts); die();
    foreach($posts as $post){
      // echo $post['post_id']; die(); //The value is getting here but not in the below function
    $likes = $this->umodel->get_like(['post_id'=>$post['post_id']<!-- not getting value here -->, 'user_id'=>$this->session->userdata('user_id')]);
    // echo $post['post_id']; die(); //Also getting the value here
    }

  }
```

I am trying to get the value of post_id from the second function of the model, I am also geeting that. But the problem is that when I am trying to pass that value as a parameter in the second function, the variable is not getting there. And when manually I put the value in the function, I am getting the result. see the comments in the code. Why it is not getting the value of post_id in the parameter of the function?

Comment: try `var_dump($array);die;` in `get_like` function and share the output

Comment: The result of var_dump($likes); die(); is NULL. It is not getting the post_id in the parameter of the function. Why is it so?

Comment: I am asking you `var_dump($array);die;` not `var_dump($likes); die();`

Comment: Undefined variable: array

Comment: var_dump it in `public function get_like($array){`

Comment: It is giving notice error and  asking for post_id, which is coming from second function. And when I pass post_id in the parameter, it is resulting nothing. If I directly put the id in the parameter, then it is returning the exact result. In my opinion, it;s not getting the value in the parameter.

Comment: change your `public function get_like($array){
    return $this->db->select('is_liked')
                         ->from('ims_likes')
                         ->where($array)
                         ->get()->row();

  }` to `public function get_like($array){ var_dump($array);die;
    return $this->db->select('is_liked')
                         ->from('ims_likes')
                         ->where($array)
                         ->get()->row();

  }` and share output

Comment: Sorry, the result is:array(2) { ["post_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["user_id"]=> string(2) "47" }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155686/discussion-between-b-desai-and-amit).